# ERROR in Error: The translation file (src/locale/messages.fr.xlf) locale must be provided

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

I am trying to create individual packages for each language.

I have used the below command for my angular 8 application which works fine. But when I use the same command in Angular. The translation file in that location. I am not sure why it is throwing that error.

```
ng build  --aot=true --prod --base-href=/Assignment/fr/ --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --i18n-locale=fr --outputPath=../wwwroot/fr
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I use the same command in Angular", is the version  missing from this statement?

Comment: @AkshayRana yes. sorry, it is Angular 8

Comment: It's confusing. You wrote that it works fine for angular 8. Did you mean that it worked fine for a previous version?

Comment: Just in case you find it useful we use in project package called `ngx-translate` which allows one have one app with multiple translation files which are loaded on demand

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative solution I can suggest you use  [solution](https://github.com/chathuran/angular-localization)
this will more easier than `ngx-translate` and also u can use any language as you wish, and also efficient

see the previous [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312962/angular-5-internationalization/58602823#58602823)